# Copying values from dynamic cells to specifically named columns

Tags: vba, excel

I want to import values from a dynamic worksheet to our "Database" sorted by the title of the column. As you can see I have scraped together something that works, but it is very slow and doesn't copy just the values.
The first row of the sheet is the titles, the second and further down rows are the values I want to copy.

```
Sub Copypasta()

    Sheets("copypasta").Select
    Sheets("copypasta").Range("A2").Activate
    While Not ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column) = ""
        t1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column)
        Selection.Copy
        Set MyActiveCell = ActiveCell
        Sheets("Database").Activate
        lnCol = Sheets("Database").Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:=t1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
        lnRow = Sheets("Database").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row
        If lnCol > 1 Then Sheets("Database").Cells(lnRow, lnCol).Activate Else Sheets("Database").Cells(lnRow, lnCol).Offset(1, 0).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Paste 'xlPasteValues
        Sheets("copypasta").Activate
        MyActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    Wend

End Sub
```

I tried to use PasteSpecial xlPasteValues or setting the value of the cell directly, but I can't get it to work. I am googling every error it throws and then search the code for where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copypasta()

Dim CopySht As Worksheet
Dim DBSht As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, lnCol As Long, lnRow As Long
Dim MyActiveCell As Range, FindRng As Range
Dim t1

' set the Worksheet objects
Set CopySht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("copypasta")
Set DBSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")

' set the anchor position on the loop
Set MyActiveCell = CopySht.Range("A2")

' loop through columns at the first row (until you reach a column that is empty)
While CopySht.Cells(1, MyActiveCell.Column) <> ""
    t1 = CopySht.Cells(1, MyActiveCell.Column)
    MyActiveCell.Copy

    With DBSht
        lnRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' find last row with data in Column "A"

        Set FindRng = .Rows(1).Find(What:=t1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then ' check if Find was successful
            lnCol = FindRng.Column
        Else
            lnCol = 1
        End If

         ' there's no need to use Select and Activate to Copy and/or Paste
        .Cells(lnRow + 1, lnCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

    Set MyActiveCell = MyActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) ' loop one column to the right
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: This works nearly flawless, wow! Thank you! It pastes everything past the first column one row further down though.
I fixed this with:

     `If lnCol > 1 Then Sheets("Database").Cells(lnRow, lnCol).Activate Else Sheets("Database").Cells(lnRow, lnCol).Offset(1, 0).Activate`

Comment: @KLang you're welcome,. now comes your part where you mark this as "ANSWER", by clicking the gray check-mark on the left side of my answer (it will turn green)